# Get pixel data back from programmatically generated image

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, blob

I generate array of pixels in client side JavaScript code and convert it to a blob. Then I pass URL of the blob as image.src and revoke it at image.onload callback. I don't keep any references to the data, generated by the previous steps, so this data may be freed by GC.

There are many images generated this way, and it works fine. But sometimes user may want to save the generated image by clicking on a Save button near the image. I don't want to generate image again, because generation is slow, and the image is already generated and is visible on screen. So I want to get my pixels back from the image. I tried to create canvas again, draw image on it and then call toBlob, but browser treats this image as cross origin and throws an exception: "Failed to execute 'toBlob' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': tainted canvases may not be exported". Similar errors I get with canvas.toDataUrl and canvasContext.getImageData.

Is there a workaround for this problem?

I also tried to create canvases instead of images, but when I create the second canvas, the content of the first one clears.

**Added**
 This error occurs only in the Chrome and other WebKit browsers. Firefox and MS Edge work fine. And when I commented out line of code that revoked blob url, this error disappeared - I can draw the image on the canvas and get its pixel data without CORS issues. But it is pointless to do so, because I already have blob that is not deleted.
 But my page may generate many images - it depends on its user and is unlimited. Size of images is also unlimited - it may be useful to generate even 4096x4096 images. So I want to reduce memory consumption of my page as much as possible. And all these images should be downloadable. Generation of most images uses previously generated images, so to regenerate last image in a chain, I must to regenerate all images.

So I need a workaround only for Chrome browser.

**Added 2**
 I tried to reproduce this problem in JS Fiddle, but couldn't. However locally my code doesn't work - I developed my app locally and I haven't tried running it on server. Create test.html file on your computer and open it in browser (locally, without server):

```
<html>
<body>
<pre id="log"></pre>
</body>
<script>
var log = document.getElementById("log");
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = canvas.height = 256;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
    var img = new Image();
    var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    img.src = blobUrl;
    img.onload = function()
    {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(blobUrl);
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        try { canvas.toBlob(function(blob) { log.textContent += 'success\n'; }); }
        catch(e) {log.textContent += e.message + '\n';}
    };
});
</script>
</html>
```

It will print `Failed to execute 'toBlob' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.`.
So, I think, my workaround is to detect that page is run on combination of WebKit browser and `file:///` protocol. And I can to defer revoking blob URL until page unload only for this combination.

Comment: On which browser do you get this error? Sounds like a bug. And yes, if you revoke the blobURIs, then going through a canvas is your only option since the browser would have removed the data from memory (a bit like if you did remove the file from a server after you served it). But how many images are you producing and how many should be downloadable? Can't you revoke them only on page unload? Is it hard to reproduce each image on demand?

Comment: Because you have revoked the image URL, there is no way to access the data any longer. The only thing I can say is you should only revoke the image URLs when you are sure that the data is no longer needed, because then you can set that blob URL as the `href` of an anchor with the `download` attribute without having to redraw it to a canvas.

Comment: @Kaiido it's not a bug. Blob URIs use a different protocol in the string, so it would be considered a cross-domain image.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts no, blobURIs should not be considered a cross-domain resource. They come from the browser's memory, there is even no HTTP request.

Comment: @Kaiido [according to the definition in the W3C specification](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#originOfBlobURL), there is a conflict between the definition of the "origin of a URL" and the "origin of a Blob URL", so there is an issue where some browsers may not currently treat it as a same-domain request. Regardless, though, since the URL was revoked from the blob store, using the URL must create a network error anyway.

Comment: By the way, I used the wrong term. It's not the "protocol" that differs, it's the "scheme" that differs. Sorry for the error.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts that would be known if a major browser treated blobURIs as cross-domain, it's the way we e.g resize user's inputed images. And for the revoking of the url, since it is done after the load event, it's a bug that the browser checks the origin of the image only when drawing. 3 solutions: browser bug, OP did something else to the canvas, the BLOBURI points to an svg document which contains a foreignObject (only for webkit and it's actually a bug for chrome)

Comment: Ah there is a fourth: OP executes its code from an sandboxed iframe with null origin (safari bug)

Comment: On which platform (OS)? Can you provide an [MCVE] where this occurs? Does [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ojtmhb6y/) reproduces the issue? Or [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/ojtmhb6y/1/) (which lamentably tries to make the GC to kick in...)? If you are going to open an issue on chrome's tracker, note that I can't repro on chrome 60 64-bit osx.

Comment: I found this minimal example and updated my question. And I found this bug can be reproduced only when opening page with `file:///` protocol. @Kaiido, blob contains image file that can be compressed. To show it in window, image should be uncompressed in memory. So I think that when blob is alive, browser keeps both - source blob and decompressed version of the image.

Comment: @gammaker I could reproduce too, kinda weird bug indeed. It's like chrome does check if the image is clean every time you draw it on a new canvas... And since you revoked the blobURI, I can get they don't mark it as clean anymore on the stricter `file://` protocol. Edited&Undeleted my previous answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That indeed sounds like a bug in chrome's implementation, [you may want to report it](http://bugs.chromium.org/).

What seems to happen is that chrome only checks if the image has been loaded through a clean origin when it is drawn for the first time on the canvas.

Since at this time, you already did revoke the blobURI, it can't map this URI to a clean origin (`file://` protocol is quite strict on chrome).

But there seems to be a simple workaround:

By drawing this image on <s>a</s> *[the reviver]** canvas before revoking the blobURI, chrome will mark the image as clean, and will remember it.
<sup>**[edit]* Actually it seems it needs to be the same canvas...</sup>

So you can simply create your export canvas before-hand, and draw each images on it (to save memory you can even set it to 1x1px when you don't use it for the export) **before** you do revoke the image's src:

```
// somewhere accessible to the export logic
var reviver = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');

// in your canvas to img logic
canvas.toBlob(function(blob){
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function(){
    reviver.canvas.width = reviver.canvas.height = 1; // save memory
    reviver.drawImage(this, 0,0); // mark our image as origin clean
    URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
  }
  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  probablySaveInAnArray(img);
};

// and when you want to save your images to disk
function reviveBlob(img){
  reviver.canvas.width = img.width;
  reviver.canvas.height = img.height;
  reviver.drawImage(img,0,0);
  reviver.canvas.toBlob(...
}
```

But note that this method will create a **new** Blob, not retrieve the previous one, which has probably been Collected by the GarbageCollector at this time. But it is unfortunately your only way since you did revoke the blobURI...

Comment: Thank you. I think, this trick is ideal for me. New blob is what I really need, because my initial blob is generated in BMP file format to avoid compression+decompression, but user wants to save a compressed image - PNG or JPG.

Comment: @gammaker glad it works for you too. Let me know if you're gonna report the the bug to chrome, otherwise I will tomorrow.

Comment: This bug is fixed in Chrome 61 - works in my application without workarounds. So I changed my code to apply this workaround conditionally for `Chrome < 61` when `window.location.protocol` is `file:`.